# How to access the default index page after using DirectoryIndex in .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

My site root is an english version of the site (/index.php).

I used an DirectoryIndex to point my users to a french version of the site by default (/fr/index.php).

I would like people to be able to click an link that would take them to the english version (/index.php).

Is there anyway to do this without changing the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Link to `/index.php` directly. You could also alias `/en` to `/` and serve `/index.php` when `/en` or `/en/` is requested. Example:

```
RewriteRule ^en$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Linking directly doesn't work for me unfortunately.
/index.php stays stuck on /fr/index.php and the url stays site.com/index.php